# Angular unit test for ternary condition partially working

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have to write a test case for ternary function below. For true condition my  test case is running as expected by for false it is not working as expected. I am not sure why my logic is incorrect. What changes do I need to make it work?

```
  public getData(ball: any): string {
    return ball.data === 'N/A'
      ? `<div class="noad"><p class="percentage-value-template">&#8211; &#8211;</p></div>`
      : `<div class="noad"><p class="days">${ball.data}</p></div>`;
  }
```

For true condition the below test case works fine

```
 it('should return empty if data is N/A', () => {
    comp = 'N/A';
    expect(mask.getData(comp)).toBe('');
  });
```

For false condition it is giving error

```
  it('should return empty if data is available', () => {
    comp1 = 'ABC';
    expect(mask.getData(comp1)).toBe(comp1);
  });
```

Comment: even your fist test shouldn't work, your comp should be an object containing data property {data: 'N/A'}. Furthermore your getData method is returning a div tag, so you need to modify your expect accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems... You should use toEqual() since you're testing the value of a string. Second, you're expecting `ball` to have a property called `data` but you're passing a simple string:

```
it('should return empty if data is N/A', () => {
    const ball = { data: 'N/A' }; // Pass an object with a data property
    expect(mask.getData(ball)).toEqual('');
});
```

Also, your function will never return "an empty string" - it will always return a value, just different.

For data to equal 'N/A', you will receive back:

```
<div class="noad"><p class="percentage-value-template">&#8211; &#8211;</p></div>
```

For data to NOT equal 'N/A' (say **TEST**), you will receive:

```
<div class="noad"><p class="days">**TEST**</p></div>
```

Comment: I think you have mistaken, N/A is working as expected (If condition is true)when there is no data. In the 2nd case when value is passed it throws an error (When it is not equal to N/A). ```ERROR is Expected ' ' equal to 'ABC' ```

Comment: `toEqual` is only needed for deep comparisons, i.e, when you are comparing objects or arrays. It is not required when you compare 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData` function uses a property `data` in the `ball` object to be compared with `N/A`. The function also does not return an empty string in any case. It clearly returns either one of the 2 HTML strings. So the way you have currently set up your test cases, it is impossible for the first test case to pass (even though you claim it does pass) because the function would rather return `<div class="noad"><p class="days">undefined</p></div>` since `ball.data` would be undefined if you assign a string to `ball`. With all this in mind, here's how your test cases should now look.

```js
describe('getData', () => {
    it('should return HTML string if data is N/A', () => {
        const comp = {data: 'N/A'};
        expect(mask.getData(comp)).toBe('<div class="noad"><p class="percentage-value-template">&#8211; &#8211;</p></div>');
    });

    it('should return HTML string with data if data is available and not N/A', () => {
        const comp1 = {data: 'ABC'};
        expect(mask.getData(comp1)).toBe('<div class="noad"><p class="days">ABC</p></div>');
    });
});
```